# I saved pdf file to AWS S3, but can’t download it from Chrome/Safari with https(ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: scala, google-chrome, http, firefox, amazon-s3

In Firefox(http/https) or Chrome/Safari(http) I can download it without a problem.

Code for saving:

```
saveBase64BinaryFile(SaveBinaryFile.builder()
  .namespace("namespace")
  .fileName(s"Schët-faktura_№143_ot_21_fevralya_2020.pdf")
  .contentType("application/pdf; charset=utf-8")
  .data(getFile)
  .build())


def saveBase64BinaryFile(cmd: SaveBinaryFile)(implicit context: Context): Future[FileInfo] =
  upload(
    namespace = cmd.getNamespace,
    fileName = cmd.getFileName,
    src = Source.fromFuture(Future.successful(ByteString(cmd.getData))),
    contentType = cmd.getContentType
  )

def upload(namespace: String, fileName: String, src: Source[ByteString, Any], contentType: String = null) = Future({
  val inputStream = src.runWith(StreamConverters.asInputStream())
  val fileId = UUID.randomUUID().toString
  val meta = new ObjectMetadata
  val bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)
  meta.setContentLength(bytes.length)
  meta.setUserMetadata(Map(
    FileNameHeader    → Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(fileName.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)),
    ContentTypeHeader → contentType,
  ).asJava)
  s3Client.putObject(bucketName, s3Path(namespace, fileId), new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), meta)
  FileInfo.builder()
    .fileId(fileId)
    .size(meta.getContentLength)
    .contentType(contentType)
    .name(fileName)
    .build()
})(blockEc)
```

Code for downloading:

```
def download(namespace: String, fileId: String): Future[(FileInfo, InputStream)] = Future({
  val obj = try s3Client.getObject(bucketName, s3Path(namespace, fileId)) catch {
    case e: AmazonS3Exception if e.getStatusCode == 404 ⇒ throw new NotFoundError("File not found!")
  }
  val fileName = obj.getObjectMetadata.getUserMetadata.get(FileNameHeader) match {
    case null ⇒ "file"
    case encoded ⇒ new String(Base64.getDecoder.decode(encoded), Charsets.UTF_8)
  }
  (FileInfo.builder()
    .fileId(fileId)
    .name(fileName)
    .size(obj.getObjectMetadata.getContentLength)
    .contentType(obj.getObjectMetadata.getUserMetadata.getOrDefault(ContentTypeHeader, null))
    .build(),
    obj.getObjectContent)
})(blockEc)
```

Result when I trying to open link to file from Chrome/Safari:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at [link] might be temporarily down or it may have moved
>   permanently to a new web address. ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

where could the problem be?

I tried to change the encoding, add metadata to S3. Nothing helps.

In the past, the archive with pdf docs was able to download and everything worked. But for a single document happens something strange.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a special character '№'. For downloadable archives, the names were simple, such as "ARCHIVE.zip". 
So check to save the file with a simple name and if it can be downloaded you have a problem with naming. But I can't figure out why chrome and safari with https connection do not want to save the file. Maybe someone will explain why some browsers behave so strangely?